# Setting equivalent of .subset2 in R?

Tags: r, subset, r6

In R, I can use `.subset2` to act as a `[[` or `$` without dispatch.

```
> a <- new.env()
> a$foo  <- 3
> .subset2(a, "foo")
[1] 3
```

However, I can't seem to find an equivalent for the setting operation without dispatch:

```
> .subset2(a, "foo") <- 5
```

> Error in .subset2(a, "foo") <- 5 : could not find function
> ".subset2<-"

How can I set something without the implicit dispatching of using the `[[<-` or `$<-` operators?

Comment: what is wrong with those? what are you trying to achieve that can't be done without some sort of `.subset2<-()`?

Comment: @mnist there's no .subset2<-

Comment: @mnist I am trying to override the behavior of dollar for some R6 classes. I enter into recursion if there's dispatch.

Comment: "I am trying to override the behavior of dollar for some R6 classes." Does that mean you intend to mask the `$<-` function? That could have some serious performance implications. I would recommend against masking `.Primitive` functions.

Comment: @Roland I don't care about performance. I want an error to be raised when I refer something that does not exist. You R people are way too concerned about performance

Comment: I was assuming you care about performance because you want to avoid method dispatch. If you don't care about perfomance, just write a method.

Comment: @Roland I can't use a method. See my above comments

Comment: Well, I disagree that you can't.

Comment: lol, OP is still trying to rewrite R

Comment: If you want to avoid the recursion, just use the function syntax: ``base::`$<-`(iris, Species, "x")`` and set/remove classes as necessary.

Comment: @HongOoi who are you to argue what are my needs in a language that does not allow me to code defensively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for `assign`:

> Description: Assign a value to a name in an environment.

```r
assign("foo", 5, envir = a)
```

By the way, instead of using `.subset2` (which is an internal function in the Base Package and can be confused with `subset`), you might want to use `get`:

```r
get("foo", envir = a)
# [1] 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can try

```
with(a,assign("foo",5))
```

or

```
with(a, `<-`(foo, 5))
```

or

```
a$foo <- 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure this is what you're after, but it does meet the pre-reqs of setting the value for `foo` in the `a` environment without explicitly using the `$`, `[`, `[[`, `<-` operators:

```
# Your code:
a <- new.env()
a$foo  <- 3
.subset2(a, "foo")
# Solution:
list2env(
  list(
    foo = 5
  ), 
  env = a
)
# Proof:
a$foo
```